Wireguard сервер не отправляет пакеты, что делать?
Установил вайргард на сервер, настроил. То же самое с клиентом. Обнаружил такую проблему: при попытке пинга сервера со стороны клиента идут РОВНО 2 пакета и все. Посмотрел через wg show. Пакеты отправляются, но не принимаются (число отправленных килобайтов растет во время пинга, а полученных - нет). То же самое, когда захожу на любой сайт. Подскажите, что делать, чтобы сервер также отправлял пакеты?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Небось клиент и сервер в разных странах.

да, мне же впн нужен

Если вы проспали все новости — впны давно заблокированы в РФ

нет слов... впн свой, приватный через wireguard. как его могли заблокировать если я могу пинговать свой сервер? беда в том, что пингуя в сети wireguard'а получаю только 2 пакета

Ну вот к третьему пакету роскомнадзор замечает ваш впн и блокирует, ничего сложного в этом нет

"как его могли заблокировать" - изучите что такое пакеты, как формируется трафик в целом, и так далее. Поймете, что у каждого протокола свой уникальный пакет, со своими "заголовками", своими данными, и т.д. Все это очень легко определяется. Другими словами, ваш провайдер получает пакет данных, видит, что он относится к WereGuard, ну и сразу блокирует его. Ему не важно какой там сервер, где он, какой клиент, и так далее, он смотрит только на тип. Обходной путь есть, но он не всегда работает и не везде.  Альтернатива: VLESS.

@EvgeniyZ ну почему же неважно где он. Вполне себе важно. wg на сервер внутри страны работает без проблем.
